# issue runing script on page render vs page load, in webkit

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webkit, rendering

I have a script that uses some element offsets. I intended to fire this script with :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    ...
}
```

When I use this method, all of the DOM elements are defined but the offset values are wrong. I can get the provided offsets by turning off some css values. A quick / terrible fix I applied :

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    function my_func(){
        ...
    }
    window.setTimeout(my_func, 1000);
});
```

This renders the correct offsets, but I just feel like its duct tape.

My last attempt was to force webkit to render, but this also had the wrong offsets :

```
 window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    function my_func(){
        ...
    }
    document.getElementById('wrap').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('wrap').style.display = 'block';
    my_func();
});
```

Any sugestions? or an explanation of why this happens. The browser I was testing with is Chrome.

EDIT :

The offsets are of a dom structure :

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div>
        <p>...</p>
        <p>...</p>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
   ...
</div>
```

I access the offsets by (for)lopping over the node list of "#wrap div".
If I turn off line-height and font-size I will get the offset that is calculated before the layout is fully rendered.

Adjusting line-height, font-size and display for each p and div before using offsetHeight, has no affect.

Comment: ...which... offsets... ? How do you read them ? Where do you read them ?

Comment: Are you using webfonts by any chance? Do they load before `onload` fires?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `load` instead of `ready` or *on page render* because you don't know when your CSS and images have finished loading.

If your offsets aren't right in `load` then there is something else going on.

Comment: The thing that I find interesting is that timing out the execution corrects the offsets.

Comment: Are you dynamically loading other resources? (more CSS?) or maybe it's webfonts.

Comment: yep that was it. I was using @import in the css for a font. Should I make that request with javaScript so I can fire it on statchange

Comment: or is there a way to wait for it to load.

Comment: I don't know .. is there? I've never used this feature of CSS.